What type of connector is this, and how can one reliably detach and re-attach?
These connectors are from a vintage component audio system (Kenwood X-MB3, to be specific).


Can someone help on how to reliably detach these from the base, and re-attach without any damage? The reason I ask is, I removed two exact looking connectors by trying to flip the clips on the sides with a small flat screw driver head from a Marantz MX-540 stereo audio system, and ended up breaking them. They have strand-soldered pins from the wires that slide through the top clip and go into contact holes below. I don't want to re-do this damage on the Kenwoood X-MB3.

Given the age of the board, it's possible that the connector family is discontinued. It also possible that your previous attempt was the correct way but that the plastic had become brittle with age and/or was not designed to be unplugged easily. I cannot find that connector on Digikey, which of course is not proof that it has been discontinued, but a vintage audio repair forum is probably your best bet.

Hi Vir, thanks for the snappy response. Indeed, in all fairness, the Marantz MX-540 is almost a 30-year old unit, and the plastic could have shown it's age. Hope someone can shed light on this connector.

You can try our very own Davide Andrea's very own Identiconn utility: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html

That is immensely handy! Holy cow!
The closest I could get to is this

Thank you very much.


What type of connector is this,

In the one in the first picture:
It's a ribbon cable socket.

and how can one reliably detach


Press the white button
Pull the ribbon cable
Release the button


and re-attach?


Press the white button
Insert the cable
Release the button


In the one in the second picture:
It appears to be a ribbon cable poke-in board-in component. It's a one-time permanent connection. Once the ribbon cable wires are inserted, leg springs grab the strands and won't let go. (There is a reason Molex calls them "Wire trap").
If you're determined, you can remove the cable, but expect damage to the cable and/or the component.

In the previous attempt with the Marantz, I had yanked the cable out after breaking the sides (unintentionally). Little did I realize the horror with getting the cable back in place.
I wonder why they would have such an arrangement of having clips on the sides misleading one to believe they can detach the cable and re-attach. Bizarre! No wonder, it's not found anymore.
Let this thread serve as a warning to others attempting the same.
